# How to use DP units in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a project to do, sizes are set in dp units

if there is for example a container of height 20 dp, what height should it have in Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

Flutter sizes are in DP and not pixels. They are actually called LP(Logical Pixels).

Just set it to 20 and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

From https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FlutterView/devicePixelRatio.html

> This number might not be a power of two. Indeed, it might not even be
> an integer. For example, the Nexus 6 has a device pixel ratio of 3.5.
>
> Device pixels are also referred to as physical pixels. Logical pixels
> are also referred to as device-independent or resolution-independent
> pixels.
>
> By definition, there are roughly 38 logical pixels per centimeter, or
> about 96 logical pixels per inch, of the physical display. The value
> returned by devicePixelRatio is ultimately obtained either from the
> hardware itself, the device drivers, or a hard-coded value stored in
> the operating system or firmware, and may be inaccurate, sometimes by
> a significant margin.
>
> The Flutter framework operates in logical pixels, so it is rarely
> necessary to directly deal with this property.